# function for string statistics

Tags: c++, string

The task is following.
Implement function char* stringstat(const char* s) which would count the number of characters, digits, space characters, and nonprintable characters and would output the result string in form of: characters: w digits: x spaces: y non-print: z, where w,x,y and z are the corresponding quantities.
So far i have gathered this raw material.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    char str[]="something.-21";
    int length = strlen(str);

    printf("The ASCII value of %c is %d ",character,storeAscii);
    if (storeAscii>=65 && storeAscii<=90)
    {
        printf("\nYou have entered a capital letter");
    }
    else if (storeAscii>=97 && storeAscii<=122)
    {
        printf("\nYou have entered a small letter");
    }
    else if (storeAscii>=47 && storeAscii<=57)
    {
        printf("\nYou have entered a digit ");
    }
    else if (storeAscii>=0 && storeAscii>=47
          || storeAscii>=54 && storeAscii<=64
          || storeAscii>=91 && storeAscii<=96
          || storeAscii>=123 && storeAscii<=127)
    {
        printf("\nYou have entered a special character");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know that I must have "for" cycle which checks every symbol in string and pending on the symbol adds count++ and then I can output the quantities. I really dont know how to make the cycle check for strings.

Thank you very much timrau
The final product corresponding with the task is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <cctype>
int main()
{
  char str[]="This sentence is messed up. It has 32413523.";
  int w = strlen(str);
  int x=0,y=0,z=0;

  for(char *ptr = str; *ptr!='\0';++ptr)
  {
      if(isdigit(*ptr)){x++;}
      else if(isblank(*ptr)){y++;}
      else if(isprint(*ptr)){z++;}
  }
    printf("In sentence \"%s\" there is:\n",str);
    printf("Characters: %d\n",w);
    printf("Digits: %d\n",x);
    printf("Space characters: %d\n",y);
    printf("Non-printable characters: %d\n",z);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not C, this is (poorly written, C-ish) C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cctype>

for (char *ptr = str; *ptr != '\0'; ++ptr)
{
    if (isupper(*ptr)) { /* upper case */ }
    else if (islower(*ptr)) { /* lower case */ }
    else if (isdigit(*ptr)) { /* decimal digit */ }
    else { /* special */ }
}
```